# Number of words with length 8 with certain restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How to find number of words with length 8 such in which every letter A, B, C, D occurs exactly 2 times and exactly one pair of same letters occurs on neighbouring positions? Maybe inclusion–exclusion principle can help somehow?

Comment: Since there is exactly one pair of matching letters in neighboring positions, I suspect a good way to organize the counting is by fixing that position (seven possibilities) and specifying the letter that will be duplicated there.  Also some reduction in counting can be achieved by considering mirror images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may assume that the pair of adjacent equal symbols is $AA$ (reminder: multiply by $4$ at the end to count all cases), and remove it from the string, getting an anagram of $BBCCDD$ in which there are no equal neighbours (type $N$) or exactly one pair of equal neighbours (type O).

Type $O$: we may assume that the neighbours are $BB$ (reminder: multiply by $3$ at the end) and remove them from the string, getting $CDCD,DCDC$ (type $ON$) or $CDDC,DCCD$ (type OO). Now we count, according to the sub-type, in how many positions we may re-insert the $BB$ group back, and we get that the type $O$ strings are:
$$ 3\cdot\left(2\cdot 5+2\cdot 1\right) = 36.$$

Type $N$: we may assume that the first two characters are $BC$ (reminder: multiply by $6$ at the end). If the third character is $B$, the string is forced to be $BCBDCD$. If the first three characters are $BCD$, the last three characters are either $CDB,CBD$ or $BDC,BCD$. So the type-$N$ strings are:
$$ 6\cdot(1+4) = 30.$$

For every type-$O$ string, we may re-insert the $AA$ group back in just one way. For every type-$N$ string, we may re-insert the $AA$ group back in seven ways, hence the answer to the original question is given by:

> $$ 4\cdot\left(36+7\cdot 30\right)=\color{red}{984}.$$

This sounds like a problem from an Italian mathematical competition :D

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_1$ be the set of words with the A's consecutive, $E_2$ be the set of words with the B's consecutive, and similarly for $E_3$ and $E_4$.

Using the Generalized Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,  the number of words in exactly one of the $E_i$ is given by

$\displaystyle \hspace{.2 in}\sum_{i}|E_i|-\binom{2}{1}\sum_{i<j}|E_i\cap E_j|+\binom{3}{1}\sum_{i<j<k}|E_i\cap E_j\cap E_k|-\binom{4}{1}|E_1\cap \cdots\cap E_4|$

$\displaystyle =\binom{4}{1}\underbrace{\binom{7}{1}}_{\text{AA}}\underbrace{\binom{6}{2}}_{\text{B,B}}\underbrace{\binom{4}{2}}_{\text{C,C}}-\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{2}\underbrace{\binom{6}{2}}_{\text{C,C}}\underbrace{\binom{4}{2}}_{\text{D,D}}\underbrace{\binom{2}{1}}_{\text{AA}}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{3}\underbrace{\binom{5}{1}}_{\text{AA}}\underbrace{\binom{4}{1}}_{\text{BB}}\underbrace{\binom{3}{1}}_{\text{CC}}-\binom{4}{1}\cdot4!=\color{blue}{984}$

Comment: It'd be nice to have more explanation of where each of the numbers here comes from. Maybe I'm just tired, it took me a lot of effort to figure out where each of the coefficients here is coming from.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I agree with you -- I was trying to post this using my phone, so my answer was very brief.